# How to make a hexagonal shaped "plane" in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have already asked about this on the unity forums but i thought i'd ask here too.

Basically i want to create a hexagonal shaped plane object to create terrains, however the "plane" gameobject is square, could anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a mesh with the [Mesh class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingtheMeshClass.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options....

First of all, does it have to be hexagonal, or just *look* hexagonal?

You could potentially use a texture with alpha transparency to make it appear hexagonal (although it would still be a full plane for all practical purposes, eg colliders).

Short of that, you need to create a custom mesh (model).

Again, there are lots of ways you can approach this. It's possible to do from inside Unity using code. This is very flexible, but pretty advanced.

Much simpler for now would be to use an external modelling tool (Blender is free and highly thought of).

Whatever you pick, it will almost certainly have a `Polygon circle` command that will allow you to specify how many points it should use.

Simply enter 6 here and you'll get a perfect hexagon.

Save as `.fbx` somewhere in your unity project. Unity will import the model and you can then drag it into your scene.

Answer (score 2):

find any hexa plane.obj or even .fbx online , or create it by any builder asset or using unity pro builder.

here is a hexagon.obj
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K32bE6Kb22u3rt2hl3zoAuqUOvCZlT-r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: nice coincidence, this is my shared hexagon obj!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unity's Pro Builder Asset to create custom meshes for your game.
Here is some information about it: https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder